# In what sense does the Schrödinger equation obey the De Broglie relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation

I've seen various accounts how the Schrödinger equation satisfies the De Broglie relation. However, they all show this only for the simply case of a free particle. A general solution to Schrödinger's equation in some potential would be an infinite linear combination of eigen-states for which we can't define a specific wavelength. While dwelling around the subject I thought maybe we can assign a De Broglie wavelength to the individual eigen-states which form the general solution, but that route is also problematic (for instance the eigen-states of the harmonic oscillator also don't have a well defined wavelength).

The root of the problem, I think, is that the De Broglie relation is a global relation (we can't talk about 'infinitesimal wavelength') while the Schrödinger equation is, by virtue of being a differential equation, a local relation. So, I'm struggling to see how a local relation can encode a global property like wavelength.

Comment: No, I specifically pointed out in the first sentence that I've seen the free particle argument which is what your link offers.

Answer (score 5):

The main issue here isn't superposition of eigenstates, it's the distinction between bound states and scattering states.  Particles in general don't have definite momenta, they exist as a probabilistic distribution that depends on the potential they live in.  Just like you noted, wavelengths don't make sense for a particle in a harmonic oscillator.  These are bound states, and aren't wavelike. 
 Scattering states, however, are wavelike, and it makes sense to define a de Broglie wavelength for particles in these states.

Let's assume our potential energy $V$ dies off to $0$ at $\pm \infty$.  There are two types of solutions:

$E > 0$.  Scattering states.  Because the energy is positive, and at $\pm \infty$ the potential dies off, far away from the origin (where all the exciting stuff is happening) the Hamiltonian is that of a free particle, to which you can assign a de Broglie wavelength.

$E < 0$.  Bound states.  Because the energy is negative, and the potential is $0$ at $\pm \infty$, the particle cannot exist far away from the origin.  It is trapped (bound) by the potential and hence isn't a wave.

Comment: 1) So what i infer from this is that most of the time the notion of wavelength is ill-defined but when it is then necessarily it has to satisfy the de broglie relation?  2) Bound states correspond to standing waves, no?

Comment: 1) Yes.  But I don't agree with 'most of the time' -- scattering states occur all the time, especially considering most of the universe is free space.  2) Not necessarily.  Sometimes bound states are evanescent waves (exponentially decaying) as opposed to sinusoidal (standing waves).  To get a (very rough) picture of what happens within a potential $V(x)$, let's say our particle has energy $E$.  Again, this is really rough (check out the WKB approximation for more nuance) but if $E > V(x)$ for some region in space, then you expect sinusoidal behavior, while $E < V(x)$ gets decay.